# Adjusting the height of a parent and a child frame together

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {


    int numLines = textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight;
    CGFloat goodHeight = BASE_COMMENT_HEIGHT + ((numLines-1) * textView.font.lineHeight);
    CGFloat currentHeight = textView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat heightDiff = goodHeight - currentHeight;

    if (heightDiff != 0) {
        CGRect containerFrame = self.commentInputContainer.frame;
        containerFrame.size.height += heightDiff;
        containerFrame.origin.y -= heightDiff;
        self.commentInputContainer.frame = containerFrame;

        CGRect commentFrame = self.inlineCommentField.frame;
        commentFrame.origin.y -= heightDiff;
        commentFrame.size.height += heightDiff;
        self.inlineCommentField.frame = commentFrame;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I am trying to adjust the size of a comment field dynamically. When the number of lines of comment increases, I intend to increase the field's size and the field's container's size.

The problem with the above code is, however, when I try to adjust the size of both the parent (container) and the child (commentField) the child's size doesn't change.

Why is this happening, and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: you should use auto layout to change height and it should be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

To get a UITextView that resizes to display the current text input, you can disable scrolling and use autolayout. Make the textView's superview's height dependent on the textView's height.